# How to remove bold fonts from an entire document?

Tags: koma-script, bold

Following your suggestions below, I would like to modify the colo and the sizers of the chapters, sections, subsections and so on following the style of `classicthesis`, but with a `scrbook` class : without any bold font. Is my preamble correct? This is my MWE:

```
    \documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat]%
{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape\small}%changed to small caps in headers
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{part}{\scshape\small}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\scshape\Large}
\addtokomafont{section}{\scshape\small}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\itshape}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\itshape}
\addtokomafont{paragraph}{\scshape\small}
\addtokomafont{subparagraph}{\scshape\small}

\begin{document}
    \chapter(A title)
    \section{A section}
    \subsection{A subsection in italics}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ad package `blindtext` and add some `\blindtext` where your real text would be. Examine the output. Is it what  you expect? Or not?

Comment: Yes, it is what I expected. It is very close to classicthesis style. Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The KOMA-Script way to change font attributes is using `\addtokomafont` or `\setkomafont`. In your preamble, add

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
```

and you remove all bold fonts in table of contents and sectioning commands (part, chapter, section *etc*.), without touching the other part of the definition.

See page 54 *ff*. in the [English manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) (table 3.2) for a list of elements you can change using these two commands.

Your MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat]%
{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
    \chapter(A title)
    \section{A section}
    \subsection{A subsection in italics}
\end{document}
```

By using the documented interface when changing font attributes, you avoid later possible ‘surprises’. (*DISCLAIMER*: I am not implying that TeXnician and egreg’s solutions will give you future surprises.)

Answer (score 6):

If you really want no bold font in your document then do `\let\bfseries\mdseries` in your preamble.

Alternatively you could use `\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{m}` as egreg suggested.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{m}`

Comment: It works! But, following the classicthesis style, how could set the title of the sections in small caps and in italics for the subsections and the subsubsections?

Comment: @domi Please hava a look at `\addtokomafont{section}{\scshape}` (similar for other levels).